# Why does ((*i)->getFirstName()) work, as opposed to *i->getFirstName() or Employee[*i]getFirstName()?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, dereference

Why does this line of code work in this scenario?

```
cout << ((*i)->getFirstName());
```

The context

```
class Employee{
  private:
    string FirstName;

  public:
    Employee(string FirstName);

  void setFirstName(string FName) {
    FirstName = FName;
  }

  string getFirstName(){
    return FirstName;
  }
} //End of Class
```

In the main (First name already set and Employees filled)

```
vector<Employee *> Employees;

Employees.push_back(new Employee(FirstName));

for (vector<Employee *>::iterator i = Employees.begin(); i < Employees.end(); i++) {
  cout << ((*i)->getFirstName());
}
```

My question is why did the above line work and not any of the following?

```
cout << Employee[*i]->getFirstName();

cout << Employee[i]->getFirstName();

cout << *i->getFirstName();
```

Comment: `i` is an iterator, you can't access a `vector` element using `operator[]( iterator )`. Order of operations is that `->` gets precedence over `*`, so the `->` happens first.

Comment: Operator precedence, or order of operations.It also helps to know what types you're working with, since your first two calls that you think should work are 100% bogus.

Comment: `Employee[i]` would work if `i` were integer indexes, e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < Employees.size(); i++)`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is an iterator object, not a numerical index, so both `Employee[i]` and `Employee[*i]` are wrong (as you've seen).

Regarding `*i->getFirstName()` vs `(*i)->getFirstName()`, the `->` operator has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `*` operator. So `*i->getFirstName()` would be interpreted as if you had written `*(i->getFirstName())`, ie “execute the `getFirstName()` method on `i`, and then dereference the result". Since `i` is an iterator, and doesn't have the `getFirstName()` method, this won't compile. On the other hand, `(*i)->getFirstName()` would be interpreted as "dereference the `i` iterator to get an `Employee*`, and then execute the `getFirstName()` method on the object it points to", which is the behavior you're trying to get.

Comment: “*Since `i` is an iterator, and doesn’t have the `getFirstName()` method, this won’t compile*” - that is not the reason why. An iterator can be dereferenced with `->`, yielding a reference to the element it refers to. But, since the element in this case is a pointer, you can’t call a method on a pointer, only on the object the pointer is pointing at. Which is why an additional dereference is needed.